# Microsoft Access 2010 Duplicates Error Occurs Too Late

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Microsoft Access with a field that is set to Indexed = Yes (No Duplicates). The reason was to prevent the same number from being entered more than once for this field. I have an entry form for this table, and the flag works, but not as expected. It doesn't flag the user until they try to close or navigate away from the form. I think it would be much more helpful if the user got an error as soon as they try to leave the field they have entered an invalid value for. Is this possible? I think it will be frustrating for users if errors start popping up once they've finished entering data and I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the field's onExit event to:

1. Either check if the value is already in present using `Dlookup()`?
2. OR try to commit your changes by `if me.dirty then me.dirty = false`

Eitherway, this is a design issue. You should concider re-designing your table structure. If you provide code, you might get better answer.

Comment: There is currently no code used. I started with a basic table setup and set the "Indexed" property to "Yes (No Duplicates)" in design view of the table. From this table, there is a very basic entry form. I wasn't sure if this was the appropriate approach since as I mentioned the behaviour isn't as expected. I will try using the OnExit event instead and let you know how it goes, thank you!

Comment: I used the BeforeUpdate event and Dlookup() to produce an error message and it worked much better. Thank you.